# codeigniter v 2.2.6 url encode didnt work for :num

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My routes are:

```
$apartment = urlencode('διαμερίσματα');
$wild = '/(:num)';
$secondwild =  urlencode('/(:num)'));
...
$route[$apartment] = 'page/apartments';
$route[$apartment.$wild.$secondwild] = 'page/apartment/$1/$2'; //problem route
```

In my problem route line the secondwild value is a Greek(language) word and it didn't recognize urlencode function on :num. I get a message on browser:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /igntest/Î´Î¹Î±Î¼ÎµÏÎ¯ÏƒÎ¼Î±Ï„Î±/1/Î”Î¹ÎµÏÎ¸Ï…Î½ÏƒÎ· was not found on this server.
```

What may be the problem? (codeigniter v 2.2.6)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to URL-encode `(:num)`, `(:any)` and other similar wildcards ... It doesn't even make sense to do that.

Comment: Url didn't work for Greek words only for English and I need that for url seo.

Comment: No but the wildcard key which replace (:num) is a Greek word. I check it this work only for English word. How to make it this work for Greek?

Comment: `(:num)` catches **num**bers, not words ... And `(:any)` catches everything, regardless of languages, character sets, etc.

Comment: Nor (:num) neither (:any) working. That works only for English